# new with astract class and implements

Tags: java, mmu

I have this code of Memory Managment Unit. I made an abstract algorithm Ialgo with 2 Implements.
I want to with the MMU class handle different situations. To do this i made a method that get a capacity to make the RAM and get also and Ialgo (1 of the 2 algorithm) but how i can do new for the "algo" member and get the class of the algo i've introduce on the method from the main. Here is the code:

```
public class MemoryManagmentUnit {
    private Ialgo<Integer> algo;
    private RAM ram;

    public MemoryManagmentUnit(int ramCapacity, Ialgo<Integer> algo){
        this.ram = new RAM(ramCapacity);
        this.algo = new ....?
    }
```

Comment: How is it supposed to know which implementation to use?

Comment: In the main i create for example 
FIFOAlgoImpl<String> fifo = new FIFOAlgoImpl<String>(3);
and send it to the method. And i can make also LRUAAlgoImpl

Comment: Please show an example of what you mean.

Comment: You are passing an object Ìalgo<Integer> algo`- is this meant to be stored in this.algo? If not: what's its purpose?

Comment: Normally, the way this is written, the caller of the constructor instantiates one of the 2 implementations of the Ialgo implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you hand over the algo parameter in the constructor you won't have to call new to create a new instance. You can use the instance you are injecting.

like so:

```
 public MemoryManagmentUnit(int ramCapacity, Ialgo<Integer> algo){
    this.ram = new RAM(ramCapacity);
    this.algo = algo;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.